# MediaMuxer writeSampleData error

Tags: android, audio, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I use MediaMuxer to mix audio and radio data, the data is from two encoders, the flow is correct and I get the output and play it. But the MediaMuxer maybe failed when writeSampleData because of the error :

```
 E/MPEG4Writer: timestampUs 21932611 < lastTimestampUs 22055361 for Video track
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MediaMuxer
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime: Process: org.cocos2dx.simplegame, PID: 20089
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: writeSampleData returned an error
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.MediaMuxer.nativeWriteSampleData(Native Method)
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.media.MediaMuxer.writeSampleData(MediaMuxer.java:334)
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.duapps.durecorder.muxer.DuMediaMuxer.handleMessage(DuMediaMuxer.java:53)
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-14 14:23:41.580 20089-20230/org.cocos2dx.simplegame E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I see the MPEG4Writer, The root cause of the error is the timestamp of video, It let the MediaMuxer run into IllegalState. After I did much test, I know the video and audio timestamp both maybe get the error and When I change the audio sample rate, the recurrence rate will change.

When I record only audio or radio the error can't bee recurrence.

Could someone please give me some suggestion?

Comment: The error indicates that the timestamp on the video track went backwards in time. This is not allowed.

Comment: But that should have not happen. the timestamp of video and audio are sequent.

Comment: You can check whether or not they are by logging the timestamp before each call to `writeSampleData`. The code throwing the exception is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-release/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Writer.cpp#2268

Comment: Also check if you need to set the correct position in the buffer

Comment: I have the same problem, but I try to encode only one audio channel to aac format.

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: writeSampleData returned an error...

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: writeSampleData returned an error
        at android.media.MediaMuxer.nativeWriteSampleData(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaMuxer.writeSampleData(MediaMuxer.java:682)
        at com.daasuu.mp4compose.composer.MuxRender.onSetOutputFormat(MuxRender.java:81)
        at com.daasuu.mp4compose.composer.VideoComposer.drainEncoder(VideoComposer.java:229)
        at com.daasuu.mp4compose.composer.VideoComposer.stepPipeline(VideoComposer.java:116)